# How to connect to my web server?

Tags: networking

I have implemented a simple web server as a solution to a course assignment and I want to connect to this web server over the internet. I've set it up to listen on port 22881 and configured my router accordingly as the screenshot below shows

[image]

I'm able to connect to my web server locally using `http://localhost:22881` and I can connect to the router's interface when I visit `http://my.external.ip`, but I can't connect to my web server using `http://my.external.ip:22881` (I get a connection timeout). Any idea of what may be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router either doesn't support NAT Hairpinning (also known as NAT Loopback), or it's not enabled. Try connecting from outside your home network (like from a smartphone with Wi-Fi disabled). You'll probably find that it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://simulatedsimian.github.io/tracetcp.html to track ipaddress path with ports ..

http://simulatedsimian.github.io/tracetcp_examples.html